Snap controls on custom electron title bar
So i am  deep into building an electron-react app and i want to customize the title bar (with react) without loosing the snap controls on the minimize button.
The one below is from the default chrome webapp shortcut and i want to do something similar. 
i tried using custom-electron-titlebar and it seems to be able to implement this. so how do i implement this in react and electron ipc if possible at all.

